# mysql - how to display count of a value in an extra column

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine we have a table like this:

```
id  value
 1      a
 2      b
 3      a
 4      a
 5      b
```

Query like this

```
SELECT * , COUNT( * )
FROM test
GROUP BY value
```

gives us a table like this:

```
id  value COUNT(*)
 1      a       3
 2      b       2
```

which tells us that there are three 'a' and two 'b' in our table.

The question is: is it possible to make a query (without nested SELECT's), which would yield a table like

```
id  value count_in_col
 1      a            3
 2      b            2
 3      a            3
 4      a            3
 5      b            2
```

The goal is to avoid collapsing columns and to add quantity of 'value' elements in the whole column to each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to return the specified resultset using only a single SELECT keyword.

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.value
      , COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) AS count_in_col
   FROM mytable t
   JOIN mytable u
     ON u.value = t.value
  GROUP
     BY t.id
```

to setup test case:

```
 CREATE TABLE `mytable` (`id` INT, `value` VARCHAR(1));
 INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES (1,'a'), (2,'b'),(3,'a'),(4,'a'),(5,'b');
```

returns:

```
    id  value   count_in_col  
------  ------  --------------
     1  a                    3
     2  b                    2
     3  a                    3
     4  a                    3
     5  b                    2
```

NOTE:

This assumes that `id` is unique in the table, as would be enforced by a primary key or unique key constraint.

In terms of performance, depending on cardinality, an index ... `ON (value,id)` may improve performance.

This approach (using a JOIN to match rows on the `value` column) does have the potential to produce a very large intermediate resultset, if there are a "lot" of rows that match on `value`. For example, if there are 1,000 rows with `value='a'`, the intermediate resultset for those rows will be 1,000*1,000 = 1,000,000 rows.

Adding a predicate (in the ON clause) may also improve performance, but reducing the number of rows in the intermediate result.

```
    ON u.value = t.value
   AND u.id >= t.id
```

(There's no real magic; the "trick" is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` to avoid the same `id` value from being counted more than once.)

Comment: I really don't quite understand the magic, but nevertheless thanks a lot!

Comment: @user3026384: it's not clear why you want to avoid a second SELECT within the query. In terms of performance, the approach of using a JOIN operation to match rows on the `value` column has the potential to produce a very large number of rows, when there are a large number of rows with matching `value`. (Each row with `value='a'` is going to get matched with every row with `value='a'`, for example, if there are 1000 such rows, that will produce an intermediate resultset of 1,000,000 rows. The "magic trick" is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT` to avoid counting duplicate `id`s from those million rows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is possible without a subquery to count the number of occurrences of the different values:

```
SELECT a.*,b.valCount
FROM test a
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT value,COUNT(*) AS valCount
  FROM test
  GROUP BY value
) b
ON b.value = a.value
ORDER BY a.id;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/410ba/2)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery to group the values and do the count. Then you just have to join on that subquery on the value field.

```
SELECT test.id, test.value, t2.val_count 
FROM test INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT value, COUNT(value) AS val_count FROM test GROUP BY value) AS t2
  ON test.value = t2.value;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8578/7

Edit: I just saw that you asked for an answer without using nested queries. I do not think this is possible but I will revise my answer if I find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple (and faster) SQL, but to print exact what you want, client program should parse output of `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), value, COUNT( * )
FROM test
GROUP BY value;
```

Comment: Be aware that there is a limit on the size of the string returned by the GROUP_CONCAT function.